# You uploaded an APK/Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, tried android:exported

Tags: flutter

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported
> this is my error, after adding android :exported , i got the same issue

I added android:exported in each activity on AndroidManifest.xml file but did not work

```
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.connect_one">
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<queries>
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
</intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:label="Venad"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges= 
 "orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize
```

|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|
density|uiMode"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:exported="true"
>

```
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
      
        <meta-data
          
android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
      
       
    />
    
   <activity android:name=".P2PActivity"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.P2PSampleApp"
       
       />
  
   <meta-data
       android:name="flutterEmbedding"
       android:value="2" />
   <meta-data
     android:name= 
"com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
       android:value="Connect_One" />
   <service android:name=".MeetingService"
       android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone"
       android:exported="false"
       android:stopWithTask="true"/>
   
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: usually there is three manifest file in project, show expand `app/src/` folder and you will see three folders, each contains manifest

Comment: yes, is there anything i need to change on those 2 manifest file